# Mac Tor Browser on external drive not ejected properly - now won't work!

Tags: mac

My USB ports on my Macbook are loose - I've been running Tor off of an external drive then without warning the drive disconnects... Now no matter how many wines and re-installs I do (even on the HD on the macbook) somehow it knows that it 'exited incorrectly' and WILL NOT CONNECT.

I've tried deleting the torrc file, the whole Library/Application Support contents... nothing seems to work. Where, pray tell, is Tor Browser getting that info from, that causes it to not 'take control of Tor'? There must be some file somewhere that it accesses on start-up... Anyone, PLEASE???

Thanks!!